# IOS IAP price different from Itunes connect price

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

After the price change in Europe, a tier 3 product at 2.99€ is now at 3.49€ in Itunes Connect, but displayed at 3.99€ in the application and in the final price is displayed just before buying.
Have some of you the same problem ?